# I need to loop in array and to create different documents based on the value in Variable "Level"

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I need to loop in the array but i cant fix it can someone help As of this it works fine the problem is i want to do multiple documents at once but this only ges my first value and ignores the rest

```py
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

# Open the Word template

document = Document('Kontrata.docx')

# Set the font and size for the document

font = document.styles\['Normal'\].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(9)

# List of values to filter on

filter_values = \["P-07740", "P-15539", "P-17139"\]

# Loop through each value in the list

for value in filter_values:
    \# Read in the Excel file and filter the data based on LEVEL = value
    df = pd.read_excel("./Test.xlsx", sheet_name="Per kontrate")
    df_filtered = df\[df\['LEVEL'\] == value\]

# Get the data from the filtered dataframe for the corresponding level

emri_mbiemri = f"{df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Emri'\]} {df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Mbiemri'\]}"
adresa = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Adresa'\]
nr_personal = str(df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["ID NUMBER"\])
vendi_qyteti = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Vendi/Qyteti'\]
kualifikim = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\['Kualifikim'\]
pozita = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Titulli Aktual"\]
detyrat = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Detyrat e punes"\]
pika = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Nr I pikes"\]
rruga = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Rruga"\]
fkontrata = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Fillimi I\\nkontrates"\]
mkontrata = df_filtered.iloc\[0\]\["Nenshkrimi I\\nkontrates"\]

# Open the Word template

document = Document('Kontrata.docx')

# Set the font and size for the document

font = document.styles\['Normal'\].font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(9)

# Loop through each paragraph in the document

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    \# Replace the placeholders with the corresponding data value
    if '{{emri_mbiemri}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{emri_mbiemri}}', emri_mbiemri)
    if '{{adresa}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{adresa}}', adresa)
    if '{{nr_personal}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{nr_personal}}', nr_personal)
    if '{{vendi_qyteti}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{vendi_qyteti}}', vendi_qyteti)
    if '{{kualifikim}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{kualifikim}}', kualifikim)
    if '{{pozita}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{pozita}}', pozita)
    if '{{detyrat}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{detyrat}}', detyrat)
    if '{{pika}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{pika}}', pika)
    if '{{vendi}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{vendi}}', vendi_qyteti)
    if '{{rruga}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{rruga}}', rruga)
    if '{{fkontrata}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{fkontrata}}', fkontrata)
    if '{{mkontrata}}' in paragraph.text:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{mkontrata}}', mkontrata)
\# Set the alignment for the paragraphs

# Loop through each table in the document

for table in document.tables:
\# Loop through each row in the table
    for row in table.rows:
        \# Loop through each cell in the row
        for cell in row.cells:
            \# Replace the placeholder text with the corresponding data value
            if '{{emri_mbiemri}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{emri_mbiemri}}', emri_mbiemri)
            if '{{adresa}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{adresa}}', adresa)
            if '{{nr_personal}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{nr_personal}}', nr_personal)
            if '{{vendi_qyteti}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{vendi_qyteti}}', vendi_qyteti)
            if '{{kualifikim}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{kualifikim}}', kualifikim)
            if '{{pozita}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{pozita}}', pozita)
            if '{{detyrat}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{detyrat}}', detyrat)
            if '{{pika}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{pika}}', pika)
            if '{{vendi}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{vendi}}', vendi_qyteti)
            if '{{rruga}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{rruga}}', rruga)
            if '{{fkontrata}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{fkontrata}}', fkontrata)
            if '{{mkontrata}}' in cell.text:
                cell.text = cell.text.replace('{{mkontrata}}', mkontrata)
\# Set the alignment for the cells

# Save the populated document as a new file

document.save(f"{emri_mbiemri}.docx")
```

I need to loop in the array but i cant fix it can someone help As of this it works fine the problem is i want to do multiple documents at once but this only ges my first value and ignores the rest

I need to loop in the array but i cant fix it can someone help As of this it works fine the problem is i want to do multiple documents at once

Comment: please format code correctly